# vuejs $emit in confirm dialog invalid

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I tried to get the request sent by the child page from the parent page, but it was unsuccessful。

1.parent code

```
<do-more @onreloadtab="reloadTab" :selectFolder="selectFolder"></do-more>
methods: {
      reloadTab:function(){
            console.log('reload')
      }
}
```

2.child code

```
methods: {
      async delete (row) {
        let that = this
        await this.$confirm("Are you sure to delete?", "confirm")
       .then((config) => {
             that.$emit('onreloadtab')
            return
         })
          .catch(() => {
          });
}
```

why parent cannot get emit message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a `then` method after using `await`. The `then` method is called after Promises but `await` returns the value *inside* of a Promise, rather than a Promise. So, try calling `emit` after the `await` statement without the `then` method block.

Comment: thank you,The problem is still there, but I found another way do it。

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch an event in your parent, Your need `created()` here is how you log the event in your parent

```html
<template>
  <do-more :selectFolder="selectFolder"></do-more>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{

        }
    },
    created() {
        reloadTab(event){
            console.log(event) 
        }
    }    
}
</script>
```